# C# - Get Direct Reports under another manager's Direct Reports list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, active-directory, exchangewebservices

I've been trying to figure out how to do this but I'm always met with a bump on the road. What I'm trying to do is to get the reporting people under my manager's direct reports list; so for example, "Alex" is a direct report under my manager, however, when you go into his organization you see that he also has direct reports that report directly to him - I am trying to get "those" reports not only from his side but from anyone else in the list that has direct reports as well. What is needed for me to effectively execute that idea? Many thanks!

This is my code to only get Direct Reports under my manager tree:

```
public void GetManagerDirectReports()
    {
        Application App = new Application();
        AddressEntry currentUser = App.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
        if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
        {
            ExchangeUser manager = currentUser.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
            if (manager != null)
            {
                AddressEntries addrEntries = manager.GetDirectReports();
                if (addrEntries != null)
                {
                    foreach (AddressEntry addrEntry in addrEntries)
                    {
                        ExchangeUser exchUser = addrEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.AppendLine("Name: "
                            + exchUser.Name);
                        sb.AppendLine("Title: "
                            + exchUser.JobTitle);
                        sb.AppendLine("Department: "
                            + exchUser.Department);
                        sb.AppendLine("Email: "
                            + exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress);
                        Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to go ahead and use LDAP instead of Microsoft's EWS because I saw it uses _ComObject and I don't believe that will work with what I need it to work for. Essentially, I created a master load class and then a sub-class to handle LDAP syntax which would give me the emails of all managers who have direct reports. Something I found useful while doing my research is this filter string which came in quite handy in my time of need (where "cn" is the manager's name):

```
searcher = new DirectorySearcher
        {
            Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(manager=" + cn + ",OU=Unit,OU=People,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com))"
        };
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DirectReports");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
```

Hope this can serve of some use to coming questions related to this in the future.